# Disable local changes toolbar in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, toolbar

How to disable the local changes toolbar in PhpStorm?

It shows up when working with remote files.

[image: This toolbar]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no known way to disable it.
Technically, this toolbar reminds you that you are editing remote file and it is not automatically saved apart from local files.

You may want to configure deployment with automatic upload. In this way, you will always edit your files locally and these will be auto-uploaded on save action (by timeout or changing editor focus).

More about deployment:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html